# MySQL Count IF and JOIN

Tags: mysql, count, multiple-tables, ringcentral

I have two tables:

1. `deskcases`:   `| CaseID | Resolved At(Date) | Labels |`
2. `ringcentral`:  `| Date | Type | Action Result |`

My goal is to have the following output for the previous 7 days :

```
| Date | Count of TotalResolvedCases | Count of Total Calls |
```

I need to count the cases and calls in two separate tables then join and group the counts by the date.  I'm also dealing with differing date formatting in the two tables, hence the wacky group by and join functions.

I also need to to have the join include all dates in the previous 7 days (`deskcases` has all dates so an INNER JOIN should work here I thought?)

To close, I've tried to run the following query below and it just churns with no result after a minute or two.  Any idea on how to get this working? Thank you in advance for your help! :-)

(Running MySQL 5.0.96)

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(
    deskcases.`Resolved At`,
    '%Y-%m-%d'
)AS Date1,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(deskcases.`Case #`)
    FROM
        deskcases
    WHERE
        deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Online Orders%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Internal SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.`Resolved At` > NOW()- INTERVAL 8 DAY
)AS TotalResolvedCases,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(ringcentral.Counter)
    FROM
        ringcentral
    WHERE
        `ringcentral`.`Type` = 'Voice'
    AND `Action Result` = 'Accepted'
    AND ringcentral.`Date` > NOW()- INTERVAL 8 DAY
)AS TotalCalls
FROM
 deskcases
INNER JOIN ringcentral ON DATE_FORMAT(
 deskcases.`Resolved At`,
 '%Y-%m-%d'
)= ringcentral.Date
GROUP BY
 Date1
ORDER BY
 Date1 ASC
```

## EDIT

I was able to edit this slightly to give me some result but it seems like I am counting ALL cases and calls with my sub-select queries and the totals are not being grouped by date.  Here is the code:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(
    deskcases.`Resolved At`,
    '%Y-%m-%d'
)AS Date1,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(deskcases.`Case #`)
    FROM
        deskcases
    WHERE
        deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Online Orders%'
    AND deskcases.`Case Status` LIKE '%Resolved%'
)AS TotalResolvedCases,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(ringcentral.Counter)
    FROM
        ringcentral
    WHERE
        `ringcentral`.`Type` = 'Voice'
    AND `Action Result` = 'Accepted'
)AS TotalCalls
FROM
  deskcases
LEFT OUTER JOIN ringcentral ON DATE_FORMAT(
  deskcases.`Resolved At`,
  '%Y-%m-%d'
)= ringcentral.Date
WHERE deskcases.`Resolved At` > NOW()- INTERVAL 8 DAY
GROUP BY
  Date1
ORDER BY
  Date1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should definitely not join on date.

For example you may have this data:

```
deskcases                           ringcentral
---------                           -----------
date      | whatever_d              date      | whatever_r
----------------------              ----------------------
today       x                       yesterday   u
yesterday   y
yesterday   z
```

Now, when you join them you'll get this:

```
joinedTable
-----------
date      | whatever_d  |  whatever_r
-------------------------------------
today       x 
yesterday   y              u
yesterday   z              u
```

Oops, you got 2 times an entry from ringtones table, but you wanted just 1.

So, how do you get your data? Either write 2 statements or combine them with `UNION`:

```
SELECT
DATE(`Resolved At`) AS Date1,
"Deskcases" AS fromTable,
COUNT(*) AS TotalNumber
FROM
        deskcases
    WHERE
        deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Online Orders%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Internal SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.`Resolved At` > CURDATE()- INTERVAL 8 DAY
GROUP BY 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT
`Date` AS Date1,
"ringcentral" AS fromTable,
COUNT(*) AS TotalNumber
FROM
        ringcentral
    WHERE
        `ringcentral`.`Type` = 'Voice'
    AND `Action Result` = 'Accepted'
    AND ringcentral.`Date` > CURDATE()- INTERVAL 8 DAY
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Also note, that I changed `NOW()` to `CURDATE()`. In deskcases table your date column seems to be a timestamp. When you subtract 8 days from '2013-03-20 10:06:00' you'll get '2013-03-12 10:06:00' and therefore you'll be missing all rows between '2013-03-12 00:00:00' and '2013-03-12 10:05:59'. Also I just used the `DATE()` function instead of `DATE_FORMAT()`. `DATE_FORMAT()` is a really nice and useful function in many ways, but in this case you have to type less characters when using `DATE()` :)

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT 
Date1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN fromTable = 'Deskcases' THEN TotalNumber ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDeskcases,
SUM(CASE WHEN fromTable = 'ringcentral' THEN TotalNumber ELSE 0 END) AS TotalRingcentral 
FROM (
SELECT
DATE(`Resolved At`) AS Date1,
'Deskcases' AS fromTable,
COUNT(*) AS TotalNumber
FROM
        deskcases
    WHERE
        deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Online Orders%'
    AND deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%Internal SPAM%'
    AND deskcases.`Resolved At` > CURDATE()- INTERVAL 8 DAY
GROUP BY 1, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT
`Date` AS Date1,
'ringcentral' AS fromTable,
COUNT(*) AS TotalNumber
FROM
        ringcentral
    WHERE
        `ringcentral`.`Type` = 'Voice'
    AND `Action Result` = 'Accepted'
    AND ringcentral.`Date` > CURDATE()- INTERVAL 8 DAY
GROUP BY 1, 2
) sq
GROUP BY Date1
```

Comment: Thank you for this tombom!  I definitely agree with all your points and thanks for the tips on the date functions.  There is a problem still though, I get a syntax error when I try to run your code: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(*)AS TotalNumber
FROM
 deskcases
WHERE
 deskcases.Labels NOT LIKE '%SPAM%'' at line 3"

Comment: @user1812363 Somehow something got lost there, corrected it. Please have another try.

Comment: This now works and I can see the data!  The only problem is I am feeding this query into a PHP script to present this data in a dashboard.  I noticed you informed me we should not join by date, but I'm at a loss on how to proceed from here since that is the output I need :-(

Comment: @user1812363 Have a try with the update in my answer. Not sure if I understood the problem correctly.

Comment: THANK YOU! :-) Been pounding my head against the wall on this problem for a couple days as well as how to fundamentally approach this scenario.  You have no idea how awesome this is for me. I greatly appreciate your follow up help.

Comment: @user1812363 You may also feel free to upvote me, since you're so thankful ;)